# How do I format my bootable USB Flashdrive?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, usb, format

It's not my flash drive, it's actually a friends flash drive that I borrowed, and everytime I open my Files, I see two things where Ubuntu 18.04 or 03, the latest one, Everytime I try to format the USB Drive, I can't figure it out, I mounted the flash drive with Linux Mint where you right click and it says make a bootable USB. Like I said it's a friends, and he had some files. Is there something simple I can do, or a simple terminal command, or something, everytime I try it says This partition cannot be modified because it contains a partition table; please reintialize layout of the whole device. (udisks-error-quark, 11) this is a friends USB, I'd hate to get him another one because I needed a better OS than Linux Mint(On my computer, when I installed mint the internal wifi thing on my laptop didn't support Linux Mint, Ubuntu did so that already made it better) sorry I'm long winded lol

Comment: If UEFI: UEFI only USB key, just extract ISO ( 7 zip or similar) to FAT32 formatted flash drive partition & set boot flag.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/395879/how-to-create-uefi-only-bootable-usb-live-media

Comment: If you want to restore the bootable USB flashdrive to a standard storage device, you can do it quickly and safely with mkusb. See this link, [mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=mkUSB-quick-start-manual-12.pdf), or the following link if there are still problems, [Can't format my usb drive. I have already tried with mkdosfs and gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035)

Answer (score 0):

I would use the command line as I find the Disks/Disk Creator/Whatever other GUI's gnome uses to manage partitions and disks to be clunky and broken at times, and it is much easier on the command line.

open up a terminal and type the following

```
## before plugging in usb
$ sudo fdisk -l 
## note what is displayed probably something like /dev/sda /dev/sdb etc...
## plug in usb
$ sudo fdisk -l # Whichever one isn't there is probably the usb mine is usually
## labeled /dev/sdc
$ sudo mkfs.vfat /dev/whateverYouDeterminedWasYourUsb
$ sudo dd if=/home/user/Downloads/UbuntuImage.img of=/dev/whateverYouDeterminedWasYourUsb
```

And now you should have a bootable Ubuntu usb stick :)

Answer (score 0):

The easy answer would be, install Gnome disk utility(sudo apt install gnome-disk-utility
) now launch the app through the menu (type disks) after launching check the left top corner of the disks application, find your flash drive there, click on it then after your drive options are shown click on the button with two gears, after clicking that you'll find the format option.